# преобразовать строку для извлечения значения jquery при парсинге через php

Tags: php, jquery, парсер

Новичок в php и jQuery. Пытаюсь преобразовать строку ,содержащую в себе ответ состоящий из набора имен и значений, и присваивать значение атрибуту price, но никак не выходит, направьте на верный путь пожалуйста.Прикрепляю необходимые скрины
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно собирать строку.. Вы на php собираете массив и его отдаёте. Покажите `var_dump($content)` - что там за данные получаете то посмотреть.

Comment: примеры кода лучше скидывать кодом а не скринами

Comment: Уже сам посмотрел.. И не лень было городить костыли эти.. Используйте какой-нибудь phpQuery или dom + xpath